# Iphone App can not be open after the iphone power off

Tags: iphone, ios

I met a strange problem about IOS which I can't find the way to fix.

I'm developing an App on iPhone.

It works fine when I run it in Simulator or on my iPhone device.

It works fine when I shut down my iPhone and restart the iPhone.

But it can not be opened after my iPhone's is power off, still can't be opened after the iPhone has been charged.

But when I reconnect the iPhone to the Xcode without reinstall it, it can be opened.

I don't know what the problem is and what worse is that I can't debug it cos it works fine when I debug it.

I think that must be a CoreData problem and I did something in the  applicationWillTerminate method:

```
(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    ....
    NSError *error;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Handle the error.
        } 
    }
}
```

What else am I supported to do? is there some delegate method like applicationWillTerminateWhenPowerOff to let me save the CoreData ? Or am I lose something ?

**Update**:

I fix it now. After checking the device log in organizer of Xcode, I find out the reason why it can't be opened.

It [miss the SenTestingKit frame](http://www.google.com.hk/webhp?hl=zh-CN#hl=zh-CN&newwindow=1&safe=strict&site=webhp&q=Dyld%20Error%20Message%3a%20%20%20Library%20not%20loaded%3a%20/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit%20%20%20&oq=Dyld%20Error%20Message%3a%20%20%20Library%20not%20loaded%3a%20/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit%20%20%20&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=9700l9700l0l11803l1l1l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b08d9b5c1968f27a&biw=1280&bih=603).

Comment: To debug: disconnect the iPhone, restart it, open the app, then connect the iPhone. In Xcode, on the organizer screen, you can view the device's logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a bug in applicationDidFinishLaunching or another routine called when your application starts up.

First check for crash logs in Xcode's Organizer with the device connected.

You could also put some logging code in all of your UIApplication delegate routines to see which routines (if any) are getting called and perhaps throwing an exception. [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger) is a nice utility for that since it can log from an iPhone to a Mac over WiFi.

Comment: In fact, I do the following things in applicationDidFinishLaunching:1. I get the CoreData sqlite file. 2. I set the RestKit(the rest framework) url and set the mappings there.